# Can be force MPMoviePlayerController to landscape when click on Fullscreen button in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

I create a MPMoviePlayerController in detailView(UIVIew), now i want to force MPMoviePlayerController to landscape view when user click on FullScreen button. Can i do that? Please give me any suggestion. Thanks in advance.And this is my code to create :

```
   NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:previewString];
    movieController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    [movieController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(10,130, 275 , 150)];
    movieController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [detailview addSubview:movieController.view];
    [movieController prepareToPlay];
    movieController.shouldAutoplay = NO;
```

and willEnterFullscreen () function:

```
    - (void)willEnterFullscreen:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSLog(@"willEnterFullscreen");
    donepress = YES;
    // nothing
}
```

I tried search but still do not have any good answer. Please help me. thanks so much

Comment: Have you tried with MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification?

Comment: @PoojaBohora: i added [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(willEnterFullscreen:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil]; in viewwilappear

Comment: You may rotate the view as we cannot forcefully set orientation.

Comment: @PoojaBohora: I only want to movie player view in landscape when click on FullScreen button.

Comment: I wanted to do the same and I had did it by rotating the view. Try it once. It will resolve your problem.

Comment: @PoojaBohora: Can you  example code for me, please ? I tried many code but it still can not works. Thanks so much

Comment: In my case I had done like this:
view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
view.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
add your appropriate angle for rotation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

YES, you can do that with two notification observer to change the full orientation.

First, Add two notification observer to your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
```

Second, Add the method and property

```
- (void) moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    self.allowRotation = YES;
}
- (void) moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
    self.allowRotation = NO;
}
```

Third, override the supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow method, you can return whatever orientation you want

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if (self.allowRotation) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: #import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>